# Append another file to a zip

Tags: macos, zip

Is it possible to append a file to an existing zip archive?

```
zip my_archive.zip folder_to_zip
then how to add another file to my_archive.zip
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default behaviour of zip is to add files:

```
zip zippy.zip *.sql
zip zippy.zip *.txt
zipinfo zippy.zip
    ... list of .sql and .txt files ...
```